# two maps are not homotopic equivalent

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

Let $S^1\times S^1=\{(e^{2\pi ix},e^{2\pi iy})\in\mathbb{C^2}\mid x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$,$g,h:S^1\times S^1\rightarrow S^1\times S^1$ are defined as follows:
$g(e^{2\pi ix},e^{2\pi iy})=(e^{2\pi i(2x+3y)},e^{2\pi i(x+2y)}),h(e^{2\pi ix},e^{2\pi iy})=(e^{2\pi i(2x+3y)},e^{2\pi i(x+y)})$,I want to prove they are not homotopic equivalent.I think the induced homology group by $g,h$ are not isomorphic.Can anyone show me the

Answer (score 2):

Spaces may or may not be homotopy equivalent. Maps may or may not be homotopic.

Homotopic maps induce equal maps on homology groups. The first homology group $H_1(S^1\times S^2)\equiv \Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$. With respect to the standard basis, $g_*$ and $h_*$ have matrices $\pmatrix{2&3\\1&2}$
and  $\pmatrix{2&3\\1&1}$ respectively. The matrices are different,
so the maps $g$ and $h$ are not homotopic.

Comment: As long as you've corrected the OP's use of "homotopic equivalent", let me add another correction: There's no such thing as "the induced homology group by $g,h$". There are the induced homomorphisms of homology groups, and what one wants to prove about them is not that they "are not isomorphic" but (as is shown in this answer) that they are not equal.  (And the "not not" in the title isn't intended either.)

Comment: How to compute the standard basis?"The matrices are different,the maps are not homotopic",which propostion should be applied?